# Why is the movie titled "Independence Day"?

Tags: title, independence-day

The title of the movie [*Independence Day (1996)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116629/) makes no sense to me. A country gains independence when:

1. It was depending on some other country (being ruled by another country).
2. It becomes sovereign, freeing itself from the rule of a foreign country.

The movie "Independence Day" has absolutely nothing to do with independence beside the fact that the last counter-attack by humans against the alien invaders happened to occur on the 4th of July (i.e. the American Independence Day).

Anyway, as I understand it when an enemy state invades your country and you defeat them and send them back home then that doesn't mean that you gained independence. It just means that you successfully protected yourself. Now, if the enemy state successfully invaded your country and enforced their own law upon you and then you sent them back home then yes, you gained independence. However, as I currently see it that's not what happened in the movie.

My argument is that you can't gain independence if you never depended on something. In the movie the humans certainly didn't depend upon the aliens. Hence, it makes no sense for them to commemorate an "Independence Day".

Anyway, I know that Stack Exchange answers shouldn't be primarily opinion-based. I've been using Stack Exchange for a very long time now. Hence, here's my objective question:

What's the justification for commemorating the 4th of July as a worldwide "Independence Day" in the movie? Did Roland Emmerich or Dean Devlin ever give an official explanation why?

This question has been bothering me for a long time now. Especially since I saw the new movie trailer.

Comment: You make it seem like there needs to be a more complicated reason other than "America F Yeah!"

Comment: Oh, and apparently they fought hard for the title. From IMDB: 
`The abbreviation "ID4" was invented due to legal problems with the title "Independence Day". Before 20th Century Fox reached a deal with Warner Bros. for the rights to the title, they suggested the film be called "Invasion" or "Sky on Fire" among many other titles.`

Comment: "To me, it just seems like inflated American ego boosting."  At which point you answer your own question.  The BBC recently had an article about American exceptionalism - the belief that the USA is uniquely better than anywhere else and is beyond criticism.  Although FWIW we probably would all be celebrating the aliens getting a kicking, given that it's an existential threat to the human race.

Comment: Well, why is that surprising? 99% of the scenes in the movie are in the *United States*. All of the characters are *American*. They can't coordinate with other countries very well due to the aliens disrupting world-wide communications. The *President of the United States* gives a rousing speech to *American military personal* and *American civilians* in order to boost morale before a very big, very important battle. Wouldn't it be odd if he started referencing, say, Cambodian cultural in his speech? His audience would have no idea what he's talking about.

Comment: "...you can't gain independence if you never depended on something." That's probably taking the root-words of "independence" too literally; as you note, independence has to do with a country freeing itself from being *ruled by* another country, which is typically not the same as "depending on" that country.

Comment: Also, if I recall the film correctly, by the time the final counter-offensive is launched, the world has essentially already succumbed to the aliens. The last-ditch effort to destroy the mothership really is more like an insurrection than a defensive fight, since the defensive fights (earlier in the movie) have already failed.

Comment: @Graham If that's how the BBC defined American Exceptionalism, then they've erected a magnificent straw man so that they could burn it down. AE is based on the idea that the circumstances of the founding of the US on certain principles led to a qualitatively different sort of government never seen before.  Any country that can embrace those principles can partake in that exceptionalism.

Comment: @Graham It's not like the US is alone in such nationalistic ego boosting. Even the UK was once "F yeah British Empire, all hail the (King|Queen)!" (Woops, accidentally used the full curse word initially and didn't notice, I meant to mimic cde's usage.)

Comment: @MontyHarder From a cynical perspective, the current US government does not necessarily adhere to the principles as laid down by the founders (including, among other things, the current prevalence of what could well be considered legalized bribery where Senators and Representatives receive funding from large organizations in ways that influence their votes). The US certainly has a better government than many other countries, but it is not without flaw (the issue being that there are many Americans who refuse to acknowledge the flaws, either out of nationalism or because they believe otherwise)

Comment: @JAB Yep, true enough.  The sun never sets on the British Empire, and all that.  The irony is that people too often look at the British Empire and think how wrong it was for the Brits to behave that way, but don't take the lesson themselves for their own country today,

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The 4th of July holiday in America is called *[Independence Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States))*, celebrating the day the [Thirteen Colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Colonies) made themselves a new nation, free from the British.

So from a historical point of view, it's quite logical whilst the *national holiday* is called Independence Day.

However, in the film they twist this a little. Consider the president's [rousing speech towards the end of the film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoLywiaM6PA):

> ***Perhaps it's fate that today, July         the Fourth, we will once again
>         fight for our freedom.  Not from        tyranny, persecution or
>         oppression.  But from       annihilation.***  We're fighting for        our
>   right to live, to exist.  From        this day on, the fourth day of      July
>   will no longer be remembered      as an American holiday but as the       day
>   that all of mankind declared      we will not go quietly into the
>         night.  We will not vanish without      a fight.  We will live on.  We
>         will survive.

So the President here is referring to Independence Day as primarily symbolising *the day the fight for America's freedom was won*. He then relates it to their current situation by showing how they're no longer fighting for freedom, but to avoid annihilation. But his point is, *it's still a fight*.

However this time, it's not American's fight against the British, but the world's fight against invaders - so when they win, the world can celebrate the day together, because the world will have been saved.

Of course, it doesn't *quite* make sense for it to be called Independence Day, as they're not independent of anything as you correctly surmise. However, given how the President relates it to the existing Independence Day coupled with the fact these events are occurring on 4th July, it makes sense that he is inviting the world to celebrate winning the fight on that day.

Comment: Its all very inspiring .... for us Americans.

Comment: "But his point is, it's still a fight." Such an insightful observation :)

Comment: @PreferenceBean - Yup. There was a legit point that the US has the most advanced airframes, so they'd have the best shot at putting up a fight, so maybe that's why everyone was waiting for them. They kinda undercut that argument by having one ship blown up by a hick in a cropduster though...

Comment: @T.E.D. Hehe. Sure but it was more than just fighter hardware. I will concede that the discovery of an alien craft on American soil decades earlier was the clincher in terms of allowing a solution to be devised in that nation, though this was of course pure chance. Still, they could have done more than have the RAF exclaim "well it's about bloody time!" and peoples of other nations jumping up and down in the sand with their loinclothes and tree sticks. I really don't think there's much scope for claiming that this was anything but pandering to domestic jingoism. At least, I hope not...

Comment: @PreferenceBean - Perhaps not pure chance. The USA does appear to be the [UFO Capital of the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reported_UFO_sightings#20th_century). I'm not sure why the aliens find our country so facinating, but numbers don't lie. ;-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: The plumper the pudding, the tastier the treat? :D

Comment: @T.E.D.: "They kinda undercut that argument by having one ship blown up by a hick in a cropduster though." Actually, the hick wasn't flying a cropduster when he crashed into the alien ship's primary weapon. He was *definitely* flying a figher jet that was armed with missiles. He rammed the ship because his last remaining missile was malfunctioning and wouldn't launch.

Answer (score 5):

In the movie,aliens have destroyed most cities of world and mankind's best weapon is the will to survive. I think the survival of humans in this movie is called 'Independence'

Here is what Wiki has to say about your question  justification for commemorating the 4th of July as a worldwide "Independence Day":

> With the successful implantation of the virus, Whitmore leads the attack against an alien destroyer approaching Area 51. Although the force field is deactivated and the fighters are able to inflict damage, the hull of the destroyer is too big to inflict serious damage. As a result, the fighter's supply of missiles quickly becomes exhausted. As the destroyer prepares to fire on the base, Casse has one missile left, but it jams. He decides to fly his plane directly into the alien weapon in a kamikaze attack, which kills him but destroys it. **The Americans inform resistance forces around the world about how to destroy the alien ships. The nuclear device destroys the alien mothership as Hiller and Levinson escape unharmed back to Earth. The whole world then celebrates its heroes' victory as well as its true 'Independence Day'**.

Answer (score 0):

The movie is a summary of the events that transpires on the day of American Independence; when an army of Alien beings attack the planet looking for a new habitat. The defenders of planet earth fight valiantly to save humanity from extinction and win back their independence from their evil counterparts of the galaxy. Hence, the title aptly describes the plot of the movie.

Comment: Hi Ruika, while this answer is correct, it doesn't seem to add anything to the already accepted answer. In the future, please post an answer only if you disagree with previous answers or if you have anything to add to those. You can also add to previous answers by posting your thoughts as a comment.